# Python URL Encoding Error

Tags: python

I am a novice programmer, but have been working on a plugin for MusicBrainz Picard application using python. The add-in is designed to get artist/track data from last.fm's API to automatically rate tracks.  However, I get an error and would be grateful if anybody could help me.  The error is:

> E: 19:37:25 Network request error for https://ws.audioscrobbler.com:443/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist=2%2520Chainz&api_key=0a8b8f968b285654f9b4f16e8e33f2ee&format=json: Error downloading https://ws.audioscrobbler.com:443/2.0/%3Fmethod=artist.getinfo&artist=2%252520Chainz&api_key=0a8b8f968b285654f9b4f16e8e33f2ee&format=json - server replied: Not Found (QT code 203, HTTP code 404)
>   E: 19:37:25 LastFM AutoRate: Track 2 Chainz (Fork) Error parsing response: No JSON object could be decoded

Here is the code:

```
PLUGIN_NAME = 'LastFM AutoRate'
PLUGIN_AUTHOR = 'Zachary Zuno'
PLUGIN_DESCRIPTION = '''Use LastFM to automatically rate your music 
library.'''
PLUGIN_VERSION = "0.1"
PLUGIN_API_VERSIONS = ["0.15"]

from PyQt4 import QtCore
from json import loads
from functools import partial
from picard import log
from picard.metadata import register_track_metadata_processor
from picard.webservice import REQUEST_DELAY
from picard.webservice import XmlWebService

LASTFM_HOST = "ws.audioscrobbler.com"
LASTFM_PORT = 443
LASTFM_KEY = "0a8b8f968b285654f9b4f16e8e33f2ee"
LASTFM_PATH = "/2.0"

REQUEST_DELAY[(LASTFM_HOST, LASTFM_PORT)] = 50

def encode_str(s):
    # Yes, that's right, Last.fm prefers double URL-encoding
    s = QtCore.QUrl.toPercentEncoding(s)
    s = QtCore.QUrl.toPercentEncoding(unicode(s))
    return s

def result(album, metadata, data, reply, error):
    listeners = []
    playcount = []
    try:
        data = loads(data)["artist"]
        for k, v in data.items():
            if k.startswith("stats"):
                listeners.append(v["listeners"])
            if k.startswith("stats"):
                playcount.append(v["playcount"])

        metadata["listeners"] = listeners
        metadata["playcount"] = playcount
        log.debug(u"%s: Track %s (%s) Parsed response (listeners: %s, 
playcount: %s)", PLUGIN_NAME, metadata["artist"], metadata["title"], 
str(listeners), str(playcount))
    except Exception as e:
        log.error(u"%s: Track %s (%s) Error parsing response: %s", 
PLUGIN_NAME, metadata["artist"], metadata["title"], str(e))
        finally:        
        album._requests -= 1
        album._finalize_loading(None)

def process_track(album, metadata, release, track):
    artist = metadata["albumartist"]
    path = u"/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist=%s&api_key=LASTFM_KEY&format=json" % (encode_str(artist))

    album.tagger.xmlws.download(
        LASTFM_HOST,
        LASTFM_PORT,
        path,
        partial(result, album, metadata),
        priority=True
        )
    album._requests += 1

register_track_metadata_processor(process_track)
```

Comment: Well, the error is obviously caused by the double-encoding that you say in a comment Last FM "prefers." Have you tried without that?

Comment: Where did you get this code (and the information for that comment) from? If you're copying and pasting some unspecified but ancient code (maybe another long-abandoned last.fm plugin), there's a pretty good chance it's a workaround for a bug that last.fm fixed 5 years ago, spent a couple years maintaining backward compatibility for old scripts, and finally dropped it after nobody seemed to be relying on it anymore..

Comment: The first link in your error message actually works, the problem is with your second link.

Comment: I did copy old code. Unfortunately, I'm not competent enough to know what the change is.  The issue looks to me that in the URL, ? is encoded to %3F. I tried without the double-encoding, but get the same error.  I'm stumped.

Comment: OK, from a quick google, you obviously copied this from [Florian Demmer's Picard-Last.fm.ng-Plugin](https://github.com/fdemmer/Picard-Last.fm.ng-Plugin), because you also copied his last.fm API key instead of getting your own. And for some reason you copied the earliest version of his plugin instead of the current version, so you copied a bug that he fixed in 2011. I'm not sure what to say except "don't do that". If you fix that bug, you'll still have be missing all the other fixes in the past 7 years, plus any changes to the last.fm API or to Picard's API.

Comment: I actually mostly used the original LastFM plugin. I recognized that it was updated and tried to use LastFM.ng plugin as a reference.  However, that plugin is a lot more complicated and unnecessary for what I was trying to accomplish.

I thought I was close, but maybe I'm in over my head.  Based on the comments, this seems harder to fix than I originally thought.